# How to skip a particular row and add at end of table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Dataloading
AS
BEGIN
    truncate table TABLE1

    insert TABLE1 (
        [Name],
        [Share]
    )
    select 
        [Name], 
        sum(Share)
    from TABLE2
    group by [Share]

END
```

Output:

```
texas     3000 
dallas    5000
ca        5000
sfo       7000
newyork   8000
G total  28000
alaska    4000
Total    24000
```

But I need to enter alaska at last and one row before beofre must be empty?

Note: I am leaving empty because I am sending this output in to XL sheet and there I am using some calculations. But I am doing manually is there any modifications to be done with SP.

Help me guys !!!

Comment: Why are you using SQL to create the Excel output?  If you are adding calculations to the Excel output, add a macro to insert the empty row after using @Royi's answer

Comment: I am using in Data reporting tool .Tool reads all the rows and enter in to a XL sheet.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 select 
        [Name], 
        sum(Share)
    from TABLE2
    group by [Share]

order by case when name= 'alaska' then 1 else 0 end
```

## edit

```
insert...

select [name],summ from (
 select 
        [Name], 
        cast (sum(Share) as nvarchar(100)) as summ
    from TABLE2
    group by [Share]

union all select '',''
) a 
  order by case  name when  '' then 2  
 when  'alaska' then 3    
else 1 end
```

Comment: No iam getting same output .I need to leave a empty row before alaska

Comment: oh thought you needed alaska to be at last.

Comment: its working aswesome you saved my day.Can you check the output in my question which i posted is there any chance to make changes in SP so i need not to do changes every time manually in EXCEL SHEET